# Reusing an accessors & mutators

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, accessor, mutators

In several of my models I have code like this

```
public function setTotalAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['total'] = $value * 100;
}

public function getTotalAttribute($value)
{
    return $value * 0.01;
}
```

Sometimes the field that I am mutating is called purchase or price, but the code is the same (changing 7.99 to 799 to store in the DB, and change it back on return).

If all the fields were named the same I could use a trait, however they are slightly different.... is there a way I can setup something similar to the date fields which auto-mutate to Carbon instances?

Comment: You could use `traits` (PHP >= 5.5). Or maybe `abstract` classes.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I mentioned I couldn't use traits since the name of the field is different for different models.. unless I am missing something..

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to define the fields that deal with dollars/cents conversion in the models that have such fields, and then use a trait to override the global mutators/accessors.

```
class Model
{
    use HasMoneyFields;

    protected $moneyFields = ['purchase', 'price', 'total'];
}

trait HasMoneyFields
{        
    public function getAttributeValue($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttributeValue($key);

        if (property_exists($this, 'moneyFields')) {
             if (in_array($key, $this->moneyFields)) {
                 $value /= 100;
             }
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);

        if (property_exists($this, 'moneyFields')) {
             if (in_array($key, $this->moneyFields)) {
                 $this->attributes[$key] = $value * 100;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising! Note, I use $value * 0.01 instead of division so I don't have to check for 0 (division by zero) and handle that. Thanks!

Comment: One downside is, magic calls are expensive, PHP can't optimize the code and it will be slower than proper method definitions.

Comment: Another downside is that you can only do this once. Doing this for Money, and then also doing it for something else will fail because can't use the same function name in two different traits being used at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in https://github.com/topclaudy/eloquent-mutators

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use \Awobaz\Mutator\Mutable;

    protected $accessors = [
        'title'   => 'trim_whitespace',
        'content' => 'trim_whitespace',
    ];
}
```

The package allows you to create custom accessors/mutators extensions.